# Markdown Report Not Executing in Rstudio

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, rstudio, r-markdown

I am generating the error:

```
> options(encoding='UTF-8'); require(knitr); knit('March-2013-Report.Rmd');
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: March-2013-Report.Rmd
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 4-5 (March-2013-Report.Rmd) 
Error in evaluate(code, envir = env, new_device = FALSE, stop_on_error = if (options$include) opts_knit$get("stop_on_error") else 2L) : 
  unused argument(s) (new_device = FALSE, stop_on_error = if (options$include) opts_knit$get("stop_on_error") else 2)
Calls: knit ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec -> in_dir -> evaluate

Execution halted

knitr terminated with status 1
```

when using RSTudio to knit the following code contained within a `.Rmd` file:

````
March 2013 - UGA Google Analytics Report
========================================================

```{r}
2+2
```



## About this Report


## Future Vision for GA and Web Reporting


## Analysis



### Basic Page Stats
````

I usually can debug my errors and am sure that this is something obvious, but what am I doing wrong and why doesn't this compile?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:  Session Info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.7.1      stringr_0.6.1   rga_0.8         httr_0.2        lubridate_1.2.0
[6] rjson_0.2.10    RCurl_1.95-1.1  bitops_1.0-4.1 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 digest_0.5.2    evaluate_0.4.2  formatR_0.6     knitr_1.1.8    
[6] tools_2.15.0
```

Comment: It knit just fine for me. Are your packages/RStudio up to date?

Comment: Works for me too.  You'll probably need to provide `sessionInfo()`

Comment: Session info posted.  Thanks again

Comment: Although it probably does not matter here (the real reason was explained in the comment below the answer), I recommend you to upgrade RStudio as well, because I saw `options(encoding='UTF-8')` in the log, which is not a proper way to set the encoding and has been fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess would be that it's an issue with outdated packages. Can you try updating? In RStudio, under the `packages` tab, you should have an option to update any packages which are in need.

Comment: To be specific, it is the `evaluate` package that was outdated ([#400](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/400)).

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the knitr cache - if any of the chunks have `cache=TRUE`

I usually face this problem while Knit'ng where a few of the code chunks have `cache=TRUE`